# Write Excel VBA code to save invoice data from sheet3 (Invoice ) to sheet4 (datasheet) n if invoice already exist then return to sheet3 with msg?

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(ByVal Target As Integer)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 ' Get the worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim sh1 As Worksheets
 Dim sh2 As Worksheets
 Dim fnd1 As Integer
 Dim fnd2 As Integer
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
 Set sh2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
 sh1.Range("$F$9:$F$9").Select
 sh1.Range("$F$9:$F$9").Copy
 sh2.Activate
 sh2.Range("$X$2:$X$2").Select
 sh2.Range("$X$2:$X$2").Paste
 Set fnd1 = sh2.Range("C:C").Value
 Set fnd2 = sh2.Range("X2:X2").Value
 If fnd1 = fnd2 Then
 MsgBox "Invoice Has Already Been Generated!"

 sh1.Select       ' return to invoice sheet if invoice exist
 Exit Sub
 Else
 saveinvcdata         ' Save invoice data to sheet4 using this 
 macro 
 on new invoice entry
 Exit Sub
 End If
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.CutCopyMode = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

on hover command button on invoice(sheet3) i am getting error message like "procedure declaration does not match description of event...etc" instead of generate invoice and save data on datasheet(sheet4) or if invoice data already exists then return to invoice sheet3 with message "Invoice already exists ". Please help me with this and correct my mistake inside this VBA code.

Comment: `ByVal Target As Integer`: The `CommandButton_Click` event handler doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: ok. sir then what should i do.. if i removed above then getting msg" object required" on click button.

Comment: Both `Set fnd1 = sh2.Range("C:C").Value` and `Set fnd2 = sh2.Range("X2:X2").Value` are problematic for many reasons. They should not have `Set`, and `fnd1`  needs to be `Variant`, and you can't compare them to each other directly.

Comment: @bigben sir...have done some changes to code but still not getting proper results.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim invno, rng As Range, v
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet3")
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("Sheet4")
        Set rng = ws2.Range("C:C")
    End With
    
    ' check inv number
    invno = ws1.Range("F9").Value2
    If Len(invno) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Enter Invoice Number", vbCritical
        ws1.Range("F9").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ws2.Range("X2") = invno
    
    ' search
    v = Application.Match(invno, rng, 0)
    If IsError(v) Then
        'saveinvcdata
        MsgBox "Invoice " & invno & " saved to " & ws2.Name, vbInformation, _
        "Invoice Saved"
    Else
        MsgBox "Invoice " & invno & " is on row " & v & " of " & ws2.Name, vbExclamation, _
        "Invoice Has Already Been Generated!"
    End If
    
    ws1.Range("F9").Select
    
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your effort. But i am getting error " Subscript out of Range "  at this line--> Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet3")...

Comment: @AnandKurle Do you have a sheet called "Sheet3" ?

Comment: yes... i have name it also as "Invoice"...getting error msg like " expecting object to be local" on above line

Comment: @AnandKurlw Change Sheet3 to Invoice in the code and Sheet4 to whatever that is named on the tab.

Comment: ohh great ..thats work now...but ISERROR not stoping from save invoice entry twice. how can i write IF statement to compare value of cell X2 and column " C" in sheer4

Comment: @AnandKurle What is the invoice number column formatted as on datasheet ? What is the number being duplicated ?

Comment: Sir @CDP1802  data enter in Column "C' on datasheet and after first record no duplicate entry message show on submit the invoice again. can you tell me if we paste invoice no on cell  "X2"  in datasheet and compare the same cell value with column "C" any cell value in same datasheet so how can we compare both in IF statement so that we get back to invoice sheet if record already exist.!

Comment: `Application.Match(invno, rng, 0)` checks F9 on invoice sheet with column C on datasheet

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Get the worksheets
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet ' Use "Worksheet" instead of "Worksheets"
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim fnd1 As Range ' Use "Range" for finding cells
Dim fnd2 As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set sh2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")

' Copy data from F9 on Sheet3 to X2 on Sheet4
sh1.Range("F9").Copy sh2.Range("X2")

' Find values in columns C and X
Set fnd1 = sh2.Columns("C").Find(What:=sh2.Range("X2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set fnd2 = sh2.Range("X2")

If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then ' If a match is found
    MsgBox "Invoice Has Already Been Generated!"
    sh1.Select ' Return to invoice sheet if invoice exists
Else
    SaveInvcData ' Save invoice data to Sheet4 using this macro
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Sub SaveInvcData()

```html
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Get the worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet ' Use "Worksheet" instead of "Worksheets"
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim fnd1 As Range ' Use "Range" for finding cells
    Dim fnd2 As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set sh2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
    
    ' Copy data from F9 on Sheet3 to X2 on Sheet4
    sh1.Range("F9").Copy sh2.Range("X2")
    
    ' Find values in columns C and X
    Set fnd1 = sh2.Columns("C").Find(What:=sh2.Range("X2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set fnd2 = sh2.Range("X2")
    
    If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then ' If a match is found
        MsgBox "Invoice Has Already Been Generated!"
        sh1.Select ' Return to invoice sheet if invoice exists
    Else
        SaveInvcData ' Save invoice data to Sheet4 using this macro
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub SaveInvcData()
    ' Add your code here for saving invoice data to Sheet4
End Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for the effort..but getting data saved to sheet4 with duplicate entries and not returning to invoice sheet with "already invoice" message. also got error message "peocedure declaration does not match description of event or..etc" on hover to invoice button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).